# Does exist some classes of functions dense in the Hölder space?

Tags: approximation-theory, holder-spaces

I am dealing with $f:[0,T]\to\Bbb R$, $\;\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions, with $\frac12<\alpha\le1$ such that $f(0)=0$, nowhere differentiable.

Let us denote the space of such functions with $\mathcal C^{\alpha}[0,T]$.

I already know that every function in such space is approximated in Hölder norm (not only in sup-norm!) by its Bernstein polynomials.

However I was asking myself if something similar does hold for different kind of approximating functions, which can be written explicitly as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that $C^\alpha $ is separable? At least for $\alpha =1$, this is false, as far as I know...

Comment: What about the Bernstein polynomials? They approximate every $\alpha$-Holder function wrt $\alpha$-Holder norm

Comment: That was my question: Are you sure that this is true? Where did you see that statement?

Comment: In the 2000 paper "Chebyshev and H¨older approximation", Aportaciones Mat. Comun. 27 (2000), 23–31 by J. Bustamante and M. A. Jim´enez.